# Modifying The Published Name Of A Program?

Tags: c#, clickonce, publish

I have a C# program that I poorly named when I first started it and want it changed now.  I've changed the solution name, but that doesn't appear to change what the program is named when it publishes.

My question is how to change the publish name.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the publish name? The name of the .exe that gets built, something in the metadata or something else?

Comment: If you were to look in the "Application" folder, you would see "PublishName_1_0_0_0".  This is what I mean by Publish Name

Comment: As noted in SnOrfus's answer, that's the assembly name - glad you got it to do what you want!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VS, right click the project and click properties.

Publish Tab>Options>Description

You can set the publisher name, suite name, product name etc.

edit> After your comment, then you might be looking for the Assembly Name:

Properties>Application>Assembly Name

Comment: I tried changing the "product name" field, but the published name of the program is still the same.

Comment: Note that if you change the assembly name and someone has the old version installed, it will install the new one side-by-side. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the name of the DLL, then you've to go to the project properties (not the solution) and give it the name inside the application properties tab.